# How to provide the format for timezone in moment

Tags: javascript, angular, datetime, momentjs

I am tyring to convert a time : 2019-07-25 14:00:20 UTC  in to local timezone using moment.

I am trying this:

```
moment(dateVar, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss Z').local().format('HH:mm:ss');
```

But that doesn't seems work.

Am I missing with correct format for UTC?

```
2019-07-25 14:00:20 UTC    --> 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss Z'
```

I tried finding a lot in SO for the answer, but unfortunately I couldn't find any answer for this. Can you please help.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
moment.utc('2019-07-25 14:00:20 UTC').local()
```

Comment: this will work only if the time is in UTC. If it is in some other time, i dont think it will work

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
moment(tdateVar).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

> `moment.parseZone('2016-05-03T22:15:01+02:00').utc().format();`

[Reference](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc/)